# wget vs load page with QtWebkit

Tags: javascript, webkit, wget

I am trying to understand the difference between the resulting output of a simple load page with QtWebkit and an `wget` command, apart from that QtWebkit has a large API that we can make use of in a webpage to do a lot of things with Python.

What is the process of a `wget` and how does it download a webpage with all its components (images, etc.). Is there a difference in the output size of both processes?

And last question: What is being executed (javascript) in a load page with QtWebkit (besides an `onload` event handler)?

Answer (score 1):

By default, wget does not retrieve any page requisites unless you tell it to via the [`-p`/`--page-requisites` or the `-r`/`--recursive` flags](http://man.cx/wget). It processes no JavaScript commands, nor does it attempt to do anything with the markup or CSS unless you specifically tell it to. Even then, I'm pretty sure it just uses simple string matching to determine resource names and link URLs. All in all, it's pretty stupid until you configure it correctly (the basis for just about every powerful *NIX tool).

Since the WebKit library is so extensive, it would be useful to know what you're trying to do with it, like what code are you executing. But, since you already know what you're doing is performing JavaScript calls, it's reasonable to assume that it's doing a lot more than just retrieving the page.

Perhaps if you gave some examples of what you're trying to do I would be able to more thoroughly answer your question.

Comment: it's not about examples , i'm seeking rather a document or a comparative article that shows how both of them work , maybe a process figure..